# how to link form_tag to button rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a selection box on my page, and when I click the submit button I want to take the selection choice to the server as either a post or get variable (I don't think it matters). How do I link this form:

```
<%= form_tag(store_rates_path, method: 'get') %>
  <%= label_tag(:year, "From (year)") %>
  <%= select_tag(:year, options_for_select(get_select_options(1980, 2014))) %>
```

to this button:

```
<%= button_tag(link_to("Get Rates", store_rates_path))%>
```

Comment: Do you want the request to go to `new_rate_path` or `store_rates_path` ? because your form is using the first path, but you are giving another route to the button. only put the destination in the `form_tag` line and remove the `link_to` from the `button_tag`

Comment: I want to make my selection, and the  when I click "Get rates" I want to go to the "store_rates_path", where the controller executes a bunch of methods. And I want to be able to use the options from the form as variables in those methods. sorry I see there's a typo in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to provide the path to the `form_for` method, to link it to the `rates` action of your `stores` controller:

```
<%= form_tag(store_rates_path, method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:year, "From (year)") %>
  <%= select_tag(:year, options_for_select((1980..2014).to_a)) %>
  <%= button_tag "Get Rates" %>
<% end %>
```

In your `rates` action you can then retrieve the `:year` parameter passed as follows:

```
def rates
 @year = params[:year]
end
```

You also need to define the route in your `routes.rb` file as follows, if you haven't yet:

```
get 'stores/rate', to: 'stores#rate', as: 'store_rates'
```

**IMPORTANT**

Just note that if the `rates` belong to a specific store, meaning the url is something like `stores/1/rate` then the above `get` must be `stores/:id/rate`, which also means you need to pass the `store.id` to the `store_rates_path` in your form: `store_rates_path(@store)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use rails [`submit_tag helper`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag)

```
<%= form_tag(store_rates_path, method: 'get') %>
  <%= label_tag(:year, "From (year)") %>
  <%= select_tag(:year, options_for_select(get_select_options(1980, 2014))) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Get Rates" %>
<% end %>
```

**OR**

If you want to use a link or button to submit your form parameters then you can use some js magic to achieve it:

```
<%= form_tag store_rates_path, id: "store-form", method: 'get' %>
  <%= label_tag(:year, "From (year)") %>
  <%= select_tag(:year, options_for_select(get_select_options(1980, 2014))) %>
  <%= link_to "Get Rates", "#", id: "store-form-btn" %>
<% end %>

$(document).on("click","#store-form-btn",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#store-form").submit();
});
```